# Googlmap.getCameraPosition() not working for iOS

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2

Googlemap.getCameraPosition() doesn't do any thing for iOS , neither it goes to then block or catch bolck and doesn't console anything inside it.

But on android it is working perfectly fine.

Also other methods of GoogleMap is not working for iOS, the pointer never goes to **this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY)** in case of iOS

> ```
> import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
> import { NavController,NavParams,Events, ViewController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
> import { GoogleMap, GoogleMapsEvent, GoogleMapsLatLng,CameraPosition, Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';
> import _ from 'lodash';
> ```

```
@Component({
selector: 'page-map-modal',
templateUrl: 'map-modal.html'
})
export class MapModalPage implements OnInit,AfterViewInit  {
@ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;

lat: any;
lng: any;
map:GoogleMap; 
target:any;
position:any;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
          public viewCtrl: ViewController,
          public platform: Platform,
          public events: Events,
          private alert:AlertController,
          private navParam: NavParams) {
this.target = this.navParam.get('location');
}


//get current location of user
ngOnInit() {
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((result)=>{
    this.position =  result;   
  },(error)=>{
    // console.log(error,"error occured while getting geolocation");
})
}


ngAfterViewInit(){
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.loadMap();
});
}




loadMap(){
let location = null;
if(this.target['lat'] && this.target['lng']){
    location = new GoogleMapsLatLng(Number(this.target['lat']),Number(this.target['lng']));
}else{
  location = new GoogleMapsLatLng(24.795464,46.699796);
}

this.map = new GoogleMap('map', {
  'backgroundColor': 'white',
  'controls': {
    'compass': true,
    'myLocationButton': true,
    'indoorPicker': true,
    'zoom': true
  },
  'gestures': {
    'scroll': true,
    'tilt': false,
    'rotate': true,
    'zoom': true
  },
  'camera': {
    'latLng': location,
    'tilt': 20,
    'zoom': 15,
    'bearing': 50
  }
});
this.map.setCenter(location);
this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).subscribe(() => {

  this.map.refreshLayout();
  this.map.clear();

  if((_.isEmpty(this.target['lat']) || this.target['lat'] == '0') &&  (_.isEmpty(this.target['lng']) || this.target['lng'] == '0')){ 
    this.map.getMyLocation().then((target)=>{
    location = new GoogleMapsLatLng(target.latLng.lat,target.latLng.lng);

      let position: CameraPosition = {
        target: location,
        zoom: 15,
        tilt: 30,
        bearing: 50
      };
      // // move the map's camera to position
      this.map.moveCamera(position);
      this.map.setCenter(location);
      // console.log(target.latLng.lat, target.latLng.lng,"current user location");
    },(error)=>{
      // console.log(error,"error in getting current location");
    })
  }   
});
}


dismiss(){
this.navCtrl.pop();
}


pickLocationAndDismiss(){
let target;
this.map.getCameraPosition().then((data)=>{
  target = data.target;
  this.events.publish('latlng:map',target);
}).catch(err=>{
console.log(err)
});

this.navCtrl.pop();
}


}
```